# Assistance: Website referencing in IEEE style having no author name only website or organization name using Biber in latex

Tags: biblatex, biber

I want to print an online reference (website) exactly as below:

> RedHat Corporation. Understanding Virtualization. Accessed:
> Mar. 21, 2019. [Online]. Available: https://www.redhat.com/en/
> topics/virtualization.

I am trying `.bib`  entries  with `@misc`, `@electronic`, and `@online` (using Biber) unfortunately, I am unable to print the reference as shown above.

I would appreciate if someone can provide `.bib` entries for printing different form of online website referencing for instance with author or without author name, and if an online reference has a publication date (website text with date mentioned).

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: You mention IEEE style in the title, but according to https://ieee-dataport.org/sites/default/files/analysis/27/IEEE%20Citation%20Guidelines.pdf IEEE style is slightly different. The output I get from `biblatex-ieee` (`style=ieee,`) for a straightforward entry for the reference you show looks pretty much like the online sources in this link.

Comment: Thank you for the information and link to the document. Inside document I found as follows:   General Internet Site
[2] J. Geralds, “Sega Ends Production of Dreamcast,” vnunet.com, para. 2, Jan. 31,
2007. [Online]. Available: http://nli.vnunet.com/news/1116995. [Accessed Sept.
12, 2007].

Comment: I want to print exactly: General Internet website reference but  with no author name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after some research I have a solution to my own question.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\begin{document}
\cite{Red}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

---

Biblatex Entry:
@misc{Red,
title= {{RedHat Corporation.} \textit{Understanding Virtualization.}},
url ="https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/virtualization",
month = "",
year = "",
note= "Accessed: Mar. 21, 2019",
}

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

With no [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography) is very difficult to figure out exactly what you want, but maybe this could be useful as a starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[backend=biber,urldate=long]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{MyBib.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}

\begin{document}
\cite{RedHat}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The content of the MyBib.bib file is:

```
@online{RedHat,
  title = {Red Hat corporation},
  subtitle = {Understandig Virtualization},
  url = {https://www.redhat.com/en},
  urldate = {2019-03-21}
}
```

The resulting output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you !. I need to print like as follows: RedHat Corporation. Understanding Virtualization. Accessed: Mar. 21, 2019. [Online]. Available: https://www.redhat.com/en/ topics/virtualization.

Comment: MWE:                                                  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openright,final,twoside,onecolumn]{memoir}
\begin{document}
%Biber using IEEE style for proper UTF-8 support
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

%Print all used references
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}

%Redefine References name
\defbibheading{bibliography}[References]{
 \chapter{#1}
}
\SingleSpacing
\setlength\bibitemsep{4pt}
\printbibliography[heading=bibliography]
\endgroup

\end document

Comment: @moewe         could you please answer my question?